# Change different row data into columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am a beginner in Pandas and I have been struggling with this problem for several days now.

I am using pandas, plotly and streamlit in order to create more customized charts

Below is the table I have in Pandas, which data is taken from an excel sheet

```
      Project    Status  PF_Invoice_Amount
0  FS Revadim  Not Paid              30000
1   FS Segula  Not Paid              55000
2   FS Segula      Paid              15000
3   Payita II  Not Paid             100000
4     Solfarm      Paid              32000
5    Tropigas  Not Paid              20000
6      Trufps      Paid              23000
```

I have tried to groupby but hasn’t worked

My aim is to get an output similar to Excel Pivot Tables, in pandas, as shown below

```
   Project   Paid  Not Paid
FS Revadim            30000
 FS Segula  15000     55000
 Payita II           100000
   Solfarm  32000
  Tropigas            20000
    Trufps  23000
```

You guidance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe)

Comment: What did you try with groupby exactly? That would be a good first step, so if you show that, maybe we could give more specific advice.

Comment: BTW, check out [ask], which has tips like how to write a good title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) if you have only one instance of `('Project', 'Status')` or [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with an aggregate function like `'sum'` if you have multiple instances of `('Project', 'Status')`:

```
out = df.pivot_table(index='Project', columns='Status', 
                     values='PF_Invoice_Amount', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
        .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None))
print(out)

# Output
      Project  Not Paid   Paid
0  FS Revadim     30000      0
1   FS Segula     55000  15000
2   Payita II    100000      0
3     Solfarm         0  32000
4    Tropigas     20000      0
5      Trufps         0  23000
```

[Minimal Working Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
data = {'Project': ['FS Revadim', 'FS Segula', 'FS Segula', 'Payita II', 'Solfarm', 'Tropigas', 'Trufps'],
        'Status': ['Not Paid', 'Not Paid', 'Paid', 'Not Paid', 'Paid', 'Not Paid', 'Paid'],
        'PF_Invoice_Amount': [30000, 55000, 15000, 100000, 32000, 20000, 23000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

# Output
      Project    Status  PF_Invoice_Amount
0  FS Revadim  Not Paid              30000
1   FS Segula  Not Paid              55000
2   FS Segula      Paid              15000
3   Payita II  Not Paid             100000
4     Solfarm      Paid              32000
5    Tropigas  Not Paid              20000
6      Trufps      Paid              23000
```

More information: [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe)